# How to customize the facebook friend invite box

Tags: css, facebook, invite

I have used Facebook invite friend application,I want to customize the Facebook buttons and background colors, is that possible to do so, if yes anyone can explain me? Thanks in advance

Comment: There may be trust issues concerned with doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are not able to provide a custom css for this plugin like some of the other Facebook social plugins.  The only option for customization are those that are available on the Facebook plugin page or you can set some styles on a div containing the iframe but that will basically only allow you to control position and size attributes.  The reason is that the Facebook plugins render as an iframe and cross-domain restrictions don't allow you to set css on a child iframe if the parent and child are hosted on different domains which is the case with these plugins.

Comment: so it is not possible to have that run without iframe,is there any specific code to run this application without iframe?

Comment: No - iframe is the only way (FBML code gets converted to an iframe as well).